# rotating an ellipse about an axis

Tags: java, c, angle, ellipse

if i make an ellipse bounded by a rectangle. how can i rotate it ? as in if i have rx,ry,cx,cy,topleft x,toplefy, bottomrightx,bottomrighty

iused the formula

angle=taninverse(ry/rx) 
and i keep adding the angle that is angle=angle + taninverse(ry/rx)

the angle is too small to see the difference.
please  provide another formula to calctulate teh angle with the given parmeteres

to have a look at the ellipse with the bounded rectangle frame
http://svg-edit.googlecode.com/svn/branches/2.5.1/editor/svg-editor.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried rotating by a larger angle to see what happens? Do the values of rx and ry change?

If not, you probably should compute 'atan(ry/rx)' and store the result in a variable like so:

```
double delta = Math.atan(ry / rx);
```

Then when you rotate

```
angle += delta; // or angle = angle + delta --- these are equivalent
```

Alternatively, rather than calculating the angle from ry and rx, you may wish to simply keep a value such as

```
double delta = Math.PI / 6;
```

This simply gives the angle to rotate through without a calculation. The advantage is that you can simply set this `delta` variable to any value you wish, large or small. As above, you can increment `angle` by this `delta` value.

Comment: i want the formula for the larger angle

Comment: i didnt understand... can you write like i wrote like-

angle=angle+taninverse(ry/rx)

Answer (score -1):

There are some animation classes in Android. The package android.animation is available since API 11 and provides the ability animate object properties. android.view.animation is available from API 1 and provides animations for resizing, moving, and rotating. Both also offer XML attributes so you can also set you animation in XML. The main classes to check out are android.view.animation.Animation and android.animation.Animator.

Comment: I don't see any indication that the OP is developing on Android.